# How can I attach to a specific process in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When I debug my .net core project in VSC I'm asked for a process Id to attach to. This shows a long list of running processes where I either type or scroll to find a specific process. How can I attach to a specific same process each time I want to debug?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In visual studio code your debug options can be changed in the `launch.json` file. You can get to this file quickly through debug. Simply click the cog icon to open the json file.

Here you will see configurations for your setup.

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId":"${command:pickProcess}"
    }
]
```

`name` refers to the option inside the debug dropdownlist.

Find the configuration using `processId` and change this to `processName`

`processName` is the process name to attach to. If this is used, `processId` should not be used.

The process name will be the .exe of the process id you'd normally be selecting. Once this change is made next time you debug on the option you will automatically attach to your specified process if it is running.

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "processName":"someProcess.exe"
    }
]
```

Comment: Note, I got attach working correctly by leaving out the file extension name - so in this answer "processName": "someProcess" works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is:

1. First run you app with the command `dotnet watch core`
2. The you can run the debugger on `.NET Core Attach`
3. On the list search and select .dll the file with `YourProjectName.dll`

I hope it helped.